# how to disable auto scroll

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll

I have embedded a ecwid store in my webage via iframe.

Whenever I load the page, ecwid automatically scrolls to the iframe, instead of the top of the page.

As seen here ([ecwid: how to force the scroll position](http://kb.ecwid.com/How-to-force-the-scroll-position)), ecwid's solution for this is to add the following DIV inside the {body} tag:

```
<div id="ecwid_product_browser_scroller"></div>
```

I've made a fiddle to try to make it work, but it won't happen. I do know that people have used the same code to force the bar not to scroll down, so I must be doing something wrong.

Here's the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3g20qxd/2/)

Notice that the store is forcing the bar to scroll down. I would like it to stay at the top so customers actually see the banner.

UPDATE:
Still don't know why the DIV does not work here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3g20qxd/2/).  What am I missing?

We did manage to make it work inside the [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3g20qxd/7/) but it does not work in [my website](http://www.contempecado.com/carrinho)

Comment: use pageYOffset after load of document

Answer (score 0):

I think u want to do this
add jquery as i have done

http://jsfiddle.net/v3g20qxd/7/

I have added the `pageYOffset` and `scrollBy` in this

Comment: It's almost there; it does stay at the top but the scroll is stuck, I can't move it after the page loads

Comment: it does work on the fiddle, but it does not work on my website, don't know why! Here's the link http://www.contempecado.com/carrinho

Comment: still works on the fiddle but I don't know why it won't work on my page. I've added the script source, the embedded iframe and the javascrip but it won't work. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: have u included jquery <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: yes I have. Not sure if it helps, but check the website http://www.contempecado.com/carrinho